# REGEXP help need to render 404 path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to use REGEXP to help render a 404 page in a react app using the path. I cannot figure it out.

This is the REGEXP I want; I want to match IF:

- The entire path is !== '/' && does not contain the word 'article'.

EDIT: Including code for clarification:

```
<Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route path={["/commentisfree/article/:id", "/commentisfree"]}>
          <Opinion />
        </Route>
        <Route path={["/sport/article/:id", "/sport"]}>
          <Sport />
        </Route>
        <Route path={["/culture/article/:id", "/culture"]}>
          <Culture />
        </Route>
        <Route path={["/lifestyle/article/:id", "/lifestyle"]}>
          <Lifestyle />
        </Route>
        <Route path={["/signup", "/login"]}>
          <Account />
        </Route>
        <Route path={["search/:search", "/search"]}>
          <Search />
        </Route>

        <Route path={/REGEXP[if path !== "/" && path does NOT include the word "article"]/} component={ErrorDefault} />

        <Route path={["/article/:id", "/"]}>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        
      </Switch>
```

At the bottom you'll see I've had to put the 404 component just above my index route because the 404 is never hit if I use a catch all route, it simply navigates to the index route but maintains the incorrect URL.
For example, entering http://localhost:3000/mistake takes me to the index route. I don't want this as I rely on the urls to render modular components and it doesn't work if the path is incorrect.

So i need to force any non declared paths to a 404 page where i can display a message and a link back to the home page.

Comment: Considering you can process each `line`, why don't you just check `line != '/'` and `!line.find("article")` (however you implement those checks in javascript)?

Comment: @rturrado Thankyou, I'm a bit of a noob to be honest, I'm not sure I can implement that into my react app. I have edited my original post with my code and a brief further explanation of the problem if you don't mind having a look?

Comment: Sorry I can't help! I was approaching the question from a strict regex point of view but I have no idea about javascript or react. Sorry!

Comment: No worries at all!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using React router?

If so, you could use a catch-all route at the end of the route list, which will render a 404 page, like here: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match

Edited: added link to React router documentation

Comment: I am yes, but there is a problem with that. I have edited my post with code and my problem if you don't mind having a look...

Comment: What I´ve usually done is that I´ve placed the catch-all route * last in my route declarations so that everything that falls through is caught by that route, in your case, could you switch the two bottom routes so that the catch-all route is on the bottom? If so I´m not sure you´d need the regexp at all, just a * route, since every other case would have been caught by the route declarations above. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

The following function uses [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```
    const checkRegex = (urlString) => {
        return (
          new RegExp("/").test(urlString) && new RegExp("article").test(urlString)
        );
      };
```

You can also use the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) function for this

```
    const checkRegex = (urlString) => {
        return (
          urlString.includes('article') && urlString.includes('/')
        );
      };
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with react router to determine which route to be directed to? I have edited my original post with code and brief further explanation of my problem if you wouldn't mind checking?